# Pointer Referencing and Indirection

Tags: c

If I am passing a pointer to a memory address like:

```
int main() {
  Node* start = &a1;
  int out = loop(start);
  return out;
}
```

What is the proper way to setup the pointer:

```
int loop(const Node* node) {
  Node* cur = &node;
  ...
}
```

I would think to dereference the pointer to `const Node* node` as `*node` rendering a pointer to the memory address but that is not allowed, what is allowed is `Node* cur = &node` but that is a pointer to the memory address of the passed in pointer. How to I resolve the pointer indirection in this case?

Comment: I have understood nothing.:)

Comment: If you're asking how to *cast* a pointer-to-const to just a pointer, strongly consider (a) why you need to do so, and (b) if you think you have an legitimate answer to (a), why the parameter is pointer-to-const in the first place.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, nor what you mean by "setup the pointer".

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `&node` to `cur` doesn't work because the former has type `Node **` (i.e. a pointer-to-pointer-to-Node) and the latter has type `Node *` (i.e. a pointer-to-Node).

`node` has type `const Node *` and `cur` has type `Node *`.  Both are pointers to the same type (with one being `const` and the other not), so just add `const` to `cur` and assign directly.

```
const Node *cur = node;
```

Comment: Ah, so there is pointer coercion which resolves the indirection?

Comment: I agree this must be right because,
```const Node* cur = node;
  const Node* nxt = cur->next;
  printf("%d\n", node->next);
  printf("%d\n", nxt);```
results in the same memory address for both `cur` and `nxt`.

Comment: @oliver There's no coercion.  You were trying to assign a pointer of one type to a different type.  The above uses the same types.